# Find a whole number that is both perfect square and cube found between 2000 and 10000

Tags: roots, exponentiation

"Identify a whole number that is both perfect square and cube found between 2000 and 10000?"

Can somebody help me. I am stumped on this question and I have a test tomorrow.

Comment: Such a number must be a sixth power. Now, $$4^6=4096$$

Answer (score 1):

If a number is both a perfect square and a perfect cube, it must be a sixth power. Now, $5^6 = 15625$ and $3^6 = 729$. So, the only possible number is $4^6 = 4096$.

Comment: Answer faster than me by a second haha.

Comment: Why must it be of the 6th power?

Comment: @SparticusEDM Suppose $n = a^2 = b^3$. Then $n$ is both a perfect square and perfect cube. This also implies that $a = b^{\frac{3}{2}} = b * b^{\frac{1}{2}}$ but, $b^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not a whole number unless $b$ is a perfect square. If $b$ is a perfect square, then $n$ must be a 6th power.

Comment: So to be both a perfect square and a perfect cube will a number always be a sixth power?

Comment: @SparticusEDM Correct